# Best way to clean up `QSettings` registry entries (Qt 5 on Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qsettings

Qt stores `QSettings` values in the windows registry: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

> Users normally expect an application to remember its settings (window sizes and positions, options, etc.) across sessions. This information is often stored in the system registry on Windows, and in property list files on macOS and iOS. On Unix systems, in the absence of a standard, many applications (including the KDE applications) use INI text files.

I wish to delete those entries if I un-install my Qt App. Is there an easy way to do this, without explicitly deleting all values. I am asking about a Qt function to delete all values for my particular application.

Answer (score 5):

If you initialise the QSettings object with the company and application name or using the default constructor, you can use the method [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#clear)

Example:

```cpp
QSettings settings;
settings.clear();
```

Alternatively, you can also try:

```cpp
QSettings settings(QSettings::SystemScope, "Org", "App");
settings.clear();
```